# No styles being loaded for TipTap in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tiptap

I am in the process of finding a rich text editor to add to my application and came across TipTap. It looks great so I followed a tutorial I found on YouTube however no styles are being loaded on my site.
I have been searching for a solution for ages but can't find a replication of this problem.

No styles are being loaded on render so the editor is no more than a line of text indicating the menu buttons and a blank box (which is editable) for the input area.

All of the buttons behave as expected but there are no styles.

I noticed that if I try to render a simple HTML button on another page it also comes without default styling. Is there something obvious I'm missing here? I have been searching for a solution for a few hours now.

This is how my editor looks
[image: How my editor looks]

This is how it should look
[image: How the editor should look]

This is a HTML button also showing without a default style I tried to render on another page

[image: Button with no default styles]
[image: Button with no default styles inspect]

`<button type="button">Where is the style?</button>`

I tried deleting the cache on Chrome however nothing changed

Comment: what does the console return when you inspect the design of your button ?

Comment: I inspected `bold` and the console shows it as `<button class>bold</button>`

I made a new react app to test and everything is fine in the new environment. Within the new environment `bold` is also described as `<button class>bold</button>`

Comment: I mean what do you have in the element styles, it should probably have a default style.

Comment: That's all it shows in the console, for all the buttons.
`<button class>[button name]</button>` 
But it shows the same in the new app yet all styles are applied correctly

Comment: Okay I have found out that using Tailwind completely nukes all default styles so at least I know what the problem is now. Thank you for the responses though @Asmoth

Comment: I think this is unrelated to your issue - which is just that Tailwind removes default styling from buttons - but incase anyone else got here having trouble with Tiptap not included the ProseMirror styles, it seems this is deliberate, but you can import them into you global CSS by using `@import '~prosemirror-view/style/prosemirror.css';`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is in the same boat I have found a solution, each element on the page needs to be defined explicitly within the css file. Default behaviour wasn't working as expected so for the buttons I added to the style sheet:

```
  button {
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
```

and styles appeared.

[image: Buttons with style]

Adding `.ProseMirror` to each element had no effect on its styling so I had to style elements globally. This affected other components I had made such as a `Button` component, to overcome this I added `editor` to the class name of each button in the `Editor` component

```
<button
    //
    className={editor.isActive('underline') ? 'is-active' : 'editor'} //default is '' but 'editor' added
>
```

This allowed me to style the `Editor` buttons separately

```
button.editor {
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 80x;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: ##C1BCAC;
}
```